# Implementation (.c) file conflicts with its own definition (.h) file

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a project that can calculate the weighted average of a class. In this project, I decided to split the declarations and implementations of the header files to separate .h and .c files respectively, then linking them together as object files. This worked well until I created my most recent file, a library of vector functions. When I attempt to build the project, the function signatures from vector.h conflict with the ones from vector.c. Here are the files:

vector.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

void vector_initiate_float(Vector_float *vector);

void vector_append_float(Vector_float *vector, int value);

int vector_get_float(Vector_float *vector, int index);

void vector_set_float(Vector_float *vector, int value, int index);

void vector_double_cap_if_full_float(Vector_float *vector);

void vector_free_float(Vector_float *vector);

#endif /* VECTOR_H */
```

vector.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "constants.h"
    #include "vector.h"
    void vector_append_float(Vector_float *vector, float value){
        vector_double_cap_if_full_float(vector);
        vector->data[vector->size++] = value;
    }

    float vector_get_float(Vector_float *vector, int index){
        if (index >= vector->size || index < 0) {
        printf("Index %d out of bounds for vector of size %d\n", index, vector->size);
        exit(1);
      }
      return vector->data[index];
    }

    void vector_set_float(Vector_float *vector, int index, float value){
       while (index >= vector->size) {
        vector_append_float(vector, 0);
      }

      // set the value at the desired index
      vector->data[index] = value;
    }

    void vector_double_cap_if_full_float(Vector_float *vector){
        if (vector->size >= vector->capacity) {
        // double vector->capacity and resize the allocated memory accordingly
        vector->capacity *= 2;
        vector->data = realloc(vector->data, sizeof(int) * vector->capacity);
      }
    }

    void vector_free_float(Vector_float *vector){
        free(vector->data);
    }
```

output when I run gcc -c vector.c

```
vector.c:14:6: error: conflicting types for ‘vector_append_float’
 void vector_append_float(Vector_float *vector, float value){
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from vector.c:11:
vector.h:14:6: note: previous declaration of ‘vector_append_float’ was here
 void vector_append_float(Vector_float *, int);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
vector.c:19:7: error: conflicting types for ‘vector_get_float’
 float vector_get_float(Vector_float *vector, int index){
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from vector.c:11:
vector.h:16:5: note: previous declaration of ‘vector_get_float’ was here
 int vector_get_float(Vector_float *, int);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
vector.c:27:6: error: conflicting types for ‘vector_set_float’
 void vector_set_float(Vector_float *vector, int index, float value){
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from vector.c:11:
vector.h:18:6: note: previous declaration of ‘vector_set_float’ was here
 void vector_set_float(Vector_float *, int, int);
```

As you can see, the function definitions on both files appear to conflict one another, even though this doesn't happen to any other .c and .h pair of files in my project. Searching the internet didn't bear any fruit, so I'm posting here.

Comment: C doesn't have function overloading concept, we should use the same argument & return type in both declaration & definition of the function. Here `void vector_append_float(Vector_float *, int);`  you are telling to compiler that second argument is of `int` type but while defining `void vector_append_float(Vector_float *vector, float value){ }` you are using second argument as `float` type which results in error. Use the same type.

Comment: I removed them for simplicity, the actual functions have arguments, so same result as stated above. Will revert.

Comment: They are in the question in plain sight. The function declarations (prototypes) are different from the function definitions (implementations).

Comment: It looks to me as if vector is some sort of type, is it?

Comment: vector is a struct I made. It has size, capacity and data member variables.

Comment: a header file must contains (or `#include`) every thing it needs.  In the current posted code, the header file needs the definition of `Vector_float`

Comment: vector_float is included in constants.h

Comment: Then, post the contents of `constants.h`

Comment: code should not contain `#include` statements that depend on the order of the includes.  Suggest that the file `vector.h` contain the statement: `#include "constants.h"`.  Infact since you want to make this into a library, suggest elimination of the file `constants.h`  and include its' contents in `vector.h`  That way the user only needs a single header file to be able to use the library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error messages state, there is a conflict between the declarations of the functions specified and their definitions.  Specifically:

- `vector_append_float` has a `float` for the second parameter but the declaration shows `int`.
- `vector_get_float` returns `float` but the declaration says it returns an `int`.
- `vector_set_float` taks a `float` for its third parameter but the declaration says it should be an `int`.

The declaration and definition of a function need to match.  Since the definitions seem to be using the correct type, you need to update the declarations in the header file to match.

Comment: That's it! I initially created the declarations as int in vector.h but decided to use floats in vector.c, forgetting to change them. Thank you.